# Remove newline characters from address merge field

Tags: javascript, string, merge-field

I'm using a merge field inside a piece of JavaScript Code.

```
{!Lead.Street}
```

However in some cases, the result can be an address with 2 lines, and the newline character (I suspect) is causing an illegal character exception in my JavaScript.

Here's my current JS:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!AllLeads}" var="lead">
    var leadStreet = "{!lead.Street},"
    var leadCity = "{!lead.City},";
    var leadCountry = "{!lead.Country}";

        address.push( 
               leadStreet +
               leadCity +
               leadCountry
            );

</apex:repeat>
```

Here's the JS Error I get:

[image]

Does anybody know a solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Use `JSENCODE`**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm)

> Encodes text and merge field values for use in JavaScript by inserting
>   escape characters, such as a backslash (), before unsafe JavaScript
>   characters, such as the apostrophe (').
>
> `{!JSENCODE(text)}` and replace text with the merge field or text string
>   that contains the unsafe JavaScript characters.

```
var leadStreet = "{!JSENCODE(lead.Street)},"
var leadCity = "{!JSENCODE(lead.City)},";
```